# Text Overflow in React Native. (react-native-modal)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is Login screen and modal which shows whether your username and password are correct.

[This is screen shot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe91j.png)

As you see, the text is going off the my screen. How can I fix this?

_renderModel is wrapped from normal View. It looks nasty but it's simple. This is Stylesheets Hierarchy.

modalStyle -> modalContainer -> modalTitleTextContainer, modalContentTextContainer, modalButtonContainer.

Any hint??

```
  _renderModal = () => {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}>
          <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
            <View style={styles.modalTitleTextContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.modalTitleText}>{this.props.errorMsg}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.modalContentTextContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.modalContentText}>{`It looks like ${this.state.username} doesn't match an existing account. If you don't have a Stylee account, you can create one now `}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.modalButtonContainer}>
              <Button transparent onPress={this._hideModal}>
                <Text style={styles.modalText}>Find Account</Text>
              </Button>
              <Button transparent onPress={this._hideModal}>
                <Text style={styles.modalText}>Try Again</Text>
              </Button>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

This is my parts of Style sheets.

```
  modalContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: width(100),
    height: height(30),
    padding: totalSize(2)
  },
  modalTitleText: {
    fontSize: totalSize(3),
    flex: 1
  },
  modalContentText: {
    fontSize: totalSize(2)
  },
  modalButtonText: {
    fontSize: totalSize(2)
  },
  modalButtonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  modalTitleTextContainer: {
    flex:1
  },
  modalContentTextContainer: {
    flex:1
  }
```

I'll be here to edit this post in case anything is unclear. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm still on this problem...!!!! :(

Comment: add `flexWrap: 'wrap'` to modalContainer

Comment: Um.. sorry it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the wrong width :(

Now it works fine.

```
modalContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: width(90),
    height: height(30),
    padding: 10,
    flexWrap: 'wrap'
  },
```